# Integrating jenkins email plugin to print out the output of a python script in email

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

So I have a situation here.

I have to run a Python script to get some output - for example the image-id of my machine.

I want this output to be sent as part of the email that jenkins sends after the build has been over.

I already have a groovy script which does other activities like- collecting information from Robot output files - output.xml , report.html and log.html and send out the info in the email. 
I am using email-ext plugin and robot framework for automation.

Is it possible to run - "Pre-send Script" and send the output under "Default Content" in "Eidtable email notification" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking us how to configure jenkins? Or are you asking how to run a keyword in the robot test that does something?

Comment: i am trying to ask, how to make the output of a python script, to be displayed in the email sent by jenkins. @BryanOakley

Comment: You must be able to run your python script from pre-send script (groovy code ) output  of which could be assigned to msg object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the suggestions and solutions.
Last night i used this groovy code to run my python script and pasted this groovy code under - "Default Content" of jenkins email-ext.

Code is as below :

```
<%
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()

def proc ='/var/lib/jenkins/email-templates/show_sys.py'.execute()
def b = new StringBuffer()
proc.consumeProcessErrorStream(b)
println proc.text
println b.toString()
%>
```

This is what I pasted in jenkins :

```
<h2 style="color:blue;font-size:100%;">${SCRIPT, template="vd.groovy"}</h2>
```